# PYTHON: How to take a .txt file as input from user using raw_input in Python and then read that file row wise?

Tags: python

I want to take a .txt file as input from user through `raw_input`.

Once the input is taken, I want the txt file name given by user to be accessed and the contents from it written into another file (each in next row).

I am having a problem with how to connect a and b above or how to link raw input with reading of file. I need help...the code is as follows (but it is erroneous :S).

```
import sys,os,csv

x = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:")
ui = "x" + txt
for ui in x:
    data = open("ui").readlines()
    outfile = open("myfile.csv","w")
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in data:
    row = row.strip().split(';')
    if row:
        for subrow in row:
            subrow = subrow.strip().split()
            if subrow:
                out.writerow(subrow)
outfile.close()
```

I get the error:

> cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Comment: Not sure about your error, but for a start this is wrong `ui = "x" + txt`. Do you mean `ui = x + '.txt'` ? . Similarly `data = open("ui").readlines()` should be `data = open(ui).readlines()`

Comment: `ui = str(x) + '.txt '   and open file as `fp = open(x, 'r')` and `data = fp.readlines()`

Comment: What's different here than using the shell: `cp a.txt b.txt`?

Comment: @arunKumar: iv tried that m gettin IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'd'

Comment: @KraceKumar: if i input text file called 'mine'i get 'no such file or directory mine

Comment: @KraceKumar: Thanks!:) it works but only if i input filename with extension.txt, how do i go about it if i want to enter the name only and it should be automatically taken as a text file?

Comment: ` `>>> x = str(raw_input("Enter file name :")) + '.txt'
Enter file name :krace
>>> x
'krace.txt'`

Comment: @kraceKumar: i have another prob...the file writing here that is done row-wise skips a row as it writes into "myfile.csv". how can i make it not skip a line while writing?

Comment: @user899714: can you paste sample data which you are trying to write ?

Comment: @user899714 **ame class id title rank** ? What does it mean ? There is no character ';' in this string

Comment: sorry i didn post it correctly i'' repost

Comment: name  id subject marks ranking,
mag 234 math 63 3,
sam 567 eng 56 5,
beth 890 history 78 3,
gere 123 bio 99 1,
harry 456 phy 67 4,

Comment: those separated by a ',' are in one row in the text file. sorry i cant post it properly here. name id subject marks and ranking here are all columns that have data.

Answer (score 3):

```
for row in data: 
    row = row.strip().split(';')
```

The fact that you perform `split(';')` has for consequence that a row (you should write: line) split according to ';' gives always a not empty list, even if it is an empty line, and even after having been stripped with **strip()** : `''.split(';')` gives `['']` . So your following condition `if row:` is useless.

That means that your code is equivalent to:

```
for row in data:
    row = row.strip().split(';')
    for subrow in row:
        subrow = subrow.split()
        if subrow:
            out.writerow(subrow)
```

and then to:

```
for row in data:
    for subrow in  row.strip().split(';'):
        subrow = subrow.split()
        if subrow:
            out.writerow(subrow)
```

.

Moreover , the fact that you use **split()** on **subrow** present in the list **row.strip().split(';')** eliminates all the blanks before and after each of the words present in **subrow**. So the first `strip()` in `row.strip().split(';')` is useless too.

Your code is then equivalent to:

```
for row in data:
    for subrow in row.split(';'):
        subrow = subrow.split()
        if subrow:
            out.writerow(subrow)
```

Now , `subrow.split()` can produce a void list when subrow is only blanks, because `split()` without argument has its special algorithm. So the instruction `if subrow` is usefull.

.

In fact, what your code does is, after having read the content of such a file:

```
Blackcurrant, Redcurrant   ;  Orange ; Blueberry
    Pear;Chestnut;     Lemon Lime, Grapefruit
Apple;Apricot   ;  Pineapple, Fig; Mulberry, Hedge Apple
```

to record another file like that:

```
Blackcurrant
Redcurrant
Orange
Blueberry
Pear
Chestnut
Lemon Lime
Grapefruit
Apple
Apricot
Pineapple
Fig
Mulberry
Hedge
Apple
```

I prefer the following code to do that:

```
filename = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:") + '.txt'
filepath = 'I:\\' + filename

with open(filepath) as handler,open("myfile.csv","wb") as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in handler:
        gen = ( subrow.split() for subrow in row.split(';') )
        out.writerow([x for x in gen if x])
    del out
```

.

This code will always run, even for files extremely huge whose content can't be held by the memory, because the lines of the file are read one after the other.

In case the file isn't enormous like that, it is possible to proceed like you did, with **readlines()**:

```
with open(filepath) as handler:
    data = handler.readlines()

with open("myfile.csv","wb") as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    for row in data:
        gen = ( subrow.split() for subrow in row.split(';') )
        out.writerow([x for x in gen if x])
    del out
```

But there is no particular interest to proceed so, you can do `for row in handler` as well.

.

Personnaly, I think it would be better to use writerows():

```
filename = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:") + '.txt'
filepath = 'I:\\' + filename

with open(filepath) as handler,open("myfile.csv","wb") as outfile:
    out = csv.writer(outfile)
    gen = ( x for row in handler for x in (subrow.split() for subrow in row.split(';')) )
    out.writerows([x for x in gen if])
    del out
```

.

I end this answer by informing you that a code employing a regex would be far more efficient:

```
import csv, re

regx = re.compile('[ ;\r\n]+')

filename = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:") + '.txt'
filepath = 'I:\\' + filename

with open(filepath) as handler,open("myfile.txt","w") as outfile:
    outfile.write('\n'.join(x for x in regx.split(handler.read()) if x))
```

### Edit 1

```
handler = open(filepath)
outfile = open("myfile.txt","wb")
out = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in handler:
    gen = ( subrow.split() for subrow in row.split(';') )
    out.writerow([x for x in gen if x])
del out
outfile.close()
handler.close()
```

or

```
import csv, re
regx = re.compile('[ ;\r\n]+')
filename = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:") + '.txt'
filepath = 'I:\\' + filename

handler = open(filepath)
outfile = open("myfile.txt","w") 
outfile.write('\n'.join(x for x in regx.split(handler.read()) if x))
outfile.close()
handler.close()
```

Comment: Thanks, uv gotten the problem right..bt the prob here is that m usin python 2.5 and it doesnt accept 'with'...so what to do here?

Comment: @user899714 Is it really difficult to find what to do then ? How have you opened files in Python 2.5 until now ? see my update

Comment: yes i have opened them bt only csv files usin csv.reader but not text files. I recently discovered the code above to open a text file in Python. But it leaves a row while writing data from a text file into a csv file. That is the only prob that m facin. Both ur codes above are raisin an exception of  'No such file or directory' despite givin the correct path :(

Comment: @user899714 OK, I understand now: the file to read in is also a CSV file. To use a CSV file (reading or writing), one must create a file-object, like for any other file: f = open(csvfilepath,'rb') or f = open(csvfilename,'wb') ; a file-object constitutes the interface with the Operating System (I believe) that manages the files on disk. Then a CSV-reader object must be created with rid = csv.reader(f) or a CSV-writer object with ''writ = csv.writer(f)`` . Note that the file-object f must always be opened with binary mode: **'rb'** or **'wb'** , not 'r' or 'w'

Comment: @user899714 I don't understand what is **it** in the sentence _"But it leaves a row while writing data from a text file into a csv file."_ And it shouldn't be **leaves**, I think, this verb here seems strange here

Comment: @user899714 What are the instructions concerning the specification of the path to the program ? Please, put the instruction ``print repr(path)`` in your code and give the result here surrounded with a sign ` before it and ` after. Note that it is `, a reversed quote,  not ' , the straight quote.

Comment: Sorry for the late response....i tried what u suggested, that is using the binary mode for a csv file 'wb' to write in outfile=open("myfile.csv",'wb')  and it isnt skipping a row anymore! Thank you! and thanks to stackoverflow! :)

Answer (score 0):

corrected code below

```
import sys,os,csv

x = raw_input("Enter name of file to be written row wise:")
input_filename = x + ".txt"
input_file = open(input_filename)
outfile = open("myfile.csv","wb")
out = csv.writer(outfile)
for row in input_file:
    row = row.strip().split(';')
    if row:
        for subrow in row:
            subrow = subrow.strip().split()
            if subrow:
                out.writerow(subrow)
input_file.close()
outfile.close()
```