# How do I make the code of python which get the input data from a text file with using input()?

Tags: python

I want to make the code which get the data from the text file with using input().

Concretely the file "tester.py" import the max.py and read the input.txt and,in someway the input data is pushed in the variable and the list of max.py.
I want to make that tester.py

For instance,with below 2 codes.

input.txt

```
array1
2 4 6 2
```

with
max.py

```
name=input()

array=list(map(int,input().split()))

print(name +" "+str(max(array)))
```

How do I implement it?.

Comment: you may open the file with python and read the lines. why do you insist on input function?

Comment: Because I wonder the systems of the executions of submissions of the coding tests.

Comment: As per your question, if you want to get data from a text file by using input(), then you have to pass the input file path as input(). Open and Read the data from file and do operations.

Comment: I think you are asking about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102030/python-how-to-take-a-txt-file-as-input-from-user-using-raw-input-in-python-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In most system, you can also override 'standard input file' when executing a program, telling it to read from a file instead of from keyboard. That is often system-dependant and as I don't know which one is concerned here, this simple mention should do.

For example, in unix-like system, running bash:
`python max.py < input.txt` will run max.py after replacing standard input (file 0, the console) with `input.txt`.

*More generally, the `>` operator can be use to redirect standard output, and `<` to redirect standard input. If not using file name but opened file/pipe descriptor, prefix the descriptor with `&` (e.g. `python max.py <&64`, where 64 is the file descriptor.)*

Hope that helps!

Comment: Sorry,I was intended to not using open() function.My question's sentence had deficiency.

Comment: By 'not use open() function', do you mean not using it at all or not using it with a litteral file name?

Comment: I mean that,just not using it in the max.py.

Comment: Then you probably want the second half of my answer, I'll add some detail for unix like system.

Comment: Aforementioned 'second half' is now the whole answer since capacitor7 clarified the question, don't look for the first half, it was just a (better :P) version of what Yeheshuah answered afterward (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58705094/8155816).

Answer (score 0):

*input.txt (locating at the same directory as max.py)*

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14
```

*max.py*

```py
array = []

with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
  array = [int(item) for item in file.readline().split(' ')]

# print(array)
```

**UPDATE #1**

*input.txt (locating at the same directory as max.py)*

```
2 4 6 8 10 12 14
```

*max.py*

```py
file = raw_input()
array = [int(item) for item in file.split(' ')]
# print(array)
```

*command line*

```sh
$ python max.py < input.txt
[2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14]
```

Comment: Sorry,I was intended to not using open() function.My question's sentence had deficiency.

Comment: Considering to Alceste_'s answer, added one more example.